# Python: Scrapy Gathering All Text of Selectors Children

Tags: python, css, scrapy, selector, children

I'm trying to scrape the descriptions of ebay listings, and was approaching it with this:

```
 def parse_description(self, response):
        description = response.css('div#ds_div*::text').get()
        yield {
            "description": description
        }
```

The idea was to grab the text of all the  tags that are under .css('div#ds_div')
However I'm getting this as an error:

```
"Expected selector, got %s" % (peek,))
  File "<string>", line None
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM '*' at 10>
```

Example URL I am trying to scrape: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Vintage-Toastmaster-Chrome-Toaster-Model-D182-4-Slice-Wide-Slot-Nos/114677725765?hash=item1ab3533a45:g:ui8AAOSw-jpgBbFS
Where am  I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the selector not being valid:

```
div#ds_div*::text
```

If you put a space in between the `div#ds_div` and `*` it is valid as you've also mentioned in the comments.

From looking at the link another problem is that the text you're trying to retrieve is inside an iframe with id `desc_ifr`.

If you want to scrape the content inside this iframe look at the `src` attribute of the iframe and scrape this url instead of the url in your question. Then you can do this:

```
response.css('div#ds_div p::text').get()
```

Comment: Hi, I was under the impression *::text would take the text from all child elements of that selector? I ahve also edited my original post with a an example url I'm trying to scrape the description with, could you confirm div#ds_div is infact the correct selector I'm looking for?

Comment: The reason I wanted to shorthand *::text for all child elements, is because sometimes they are wrapped in <p> or <div> etc, it really depends on how they format their description so was trying to just account for all possibilities

Comment: Ah I was making the mistake of not putting a space between the selector and the *::text, however instead of an error it just returns something blank...hmm maybe this web page isn't loading correctly

Comment: @Anonymous I've updated my answer and addressed your last comment

Comment: AH! I didn't realise Iframes worked like this, thank you so much! Learnt something :)